# pic all contact from phonebook and show with chechbox in android

Tags: android

i want to pick all contact from Android phonebook and want to store them in a list with using cursor and listview. so that i can put checkbox in the list to select multiple contact from the phonebook.

how can i achieve this ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that first of all u have to make custom layout

```
 <LinearLayout>
    <TextView ...../>
    <CheckBox....../>
 </LinearLayout>
```

now in java code place code using ContactsContracts...

```
 Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
    "DISPLAY_NAME = '" + NAME + "'", null, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String contactId =
        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    //
    //  Get all phone numbers.
    //
    Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
        Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
        int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
        switch (type) {
            case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                // do something with the Home number here...
                break;
            case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                // do something with the Mobile number here...
                break;
            case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                // do something with the Work number here...
                break;
            }
    }
    phones.close();
  // put Display name in textview id which is used in Linear Layout...
```

this is the link where u can take references..
http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/

Comment: hi jigar, code is helpful but i am not getting that what is "cr" in the above code ?